# UICollectionViewCell swipe right to remove

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm actually developing an app for my friend startup. I have a `UICollectionViewController` with horizontal custom cells and a vertical scrolling. It's just like a Facebook feed.

I would like to be able to swipe a cell to the right in a draggable way so it can goes out of the screen and perform some actions. Sort of a Tinder swipe thing but with some `UICollectionViewCell`. I don't know if `UICollectionViewController` or `UITableViewController` is better to do something like this.

For now, I just add a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` on the `collectionView` and get the cell index I swiped on. I hope you can understand, sorry for my bad english :-)

Comment: I think you should use `UITableViewController`. It will be easier for you to handle `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` ;)

Comment: you can also use mgswipecell library it's work for both side left and right and fully customize